Multi Processing. I need to pass more than one parameter to the task
from multiprocessing import Process

def del_f(f, p, args):
    """ this function calculate the gradient of the cost function at point p
        a small step in the positive direction and negative direction to calculate
        This version calls task() once for each of the parameter to compute the derivative
        for each of the parameters one at a time.
        f computes the cost function
        p is an array of the 15 parameters to optimize
        args = (aTime, aActPos)
    """
    
    def task(i):
        """ this function computes the derivative for parameter p[i].
            This is done by taking a small step in the positive and negative direction
            to compute the cost function and then find the rate of change or derivative
            of the cost function.
        """
        _save = p[i]                    # save p[i] so it can be restored later
        p[i] += h                       # take a step in the positive direction
        fpos = f(p, args)               # evaluate after taking a positive step
        p[i] = _save                    # restore p[i]
        p[i] -= h                       # take a step in the negative direction.
        fneg = f(p, args)               # evaluate after taking a negative step
        p[i] = _save                    # restore cell to its original value
        dp[i] = (fpos-fneg)/(2*h)       # calculate the gradient with P as the center value

    dp = np.zeros_like(p)               # initialize the gradient
    # create all tasks
    processes = [Process(target=task, args=(i,)) for i in range(len(p))]
    # start all processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    # wait for all processes to complete
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    return dp                           # return the gradient

I want to use gradient descent to minimize a cost function f.  f is a function of 15 parameters and finding the gradient for each one takes about 1.5 seconds, so it is slooow.  I want to compute the derivative of all 15 parameters in parallel to speed things up.   The above code give an error.  The process part of the code I copied from super fast python example.  The simple example only passes one iterable task number.  I need to make more data available to task()

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'del_f.<locals>.task'

This should be simple.   I first tested with this using a for loop to run each task() sequentially.  It works but is very slow.
def del_f(f, p, args):
    """ this function calculate the gradient of the cost function at point p
        a smal step in the positive direction and negative direction to calculate
        This version calls task once for each of the parameter to compute the derivative
        for each of the parameters one at a time.
        f computes the cost function using p
        p is an array of the 15 parameters to optimize
        args = (aTime, aActPos) These don't change 
    """
    
    def task(i):
        """ this function computes the derivative for parameter p[i].
            This is done by taking a small step in the positive and negative direction
            to compute the cost function and then find the rate of change or derivative
            of the cost function.
        """
        _save = p[i]                    # save p[i] so it can be restored later
        p[i] += h                       # take a step in the positive direction
        fpos = f(p, args)               # evaluate after taking a positive step
        p[i] = _save                    # restore p[i]
        p[i] -= h                       # take a step in the negative direction.
        fneg = f(p, args)               # evaluate after taking a negative step
        p[i] = _save                    # restore cell to its original value
        dp[i] = (fpos-fneg)/(2*h)       # calculate the gradient with P as the center value

    dp = np.zeros_like(p)               # initialize the gradient
    fp = f(p, args)
    for i in range(len(p)):             # compute the derivative for each parameter
        task(i)
    return dp                           # return the gradient

The examples I have seen pass only ONE parameter to task().  I need more so I nested task() inside another function so task() would have access to the extra parameters and be able to update the dp (derivative of p or gradient).  The cost function, f,  returns a mean squared error between the array of actual positions and the trial estimated position.
Any clue as to what is causing the pickle error?  The error seems to occur deep down in the multiprocessing.py code.

You can pass as many arguments as you want. Why do you think args is a tuple?

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+multiprocessing+can%27t+pickle+local+object+answers%3A1 for previous questions about the pickle error in multiprocessing
